# How to add download helper in a button in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I want to add a link in a table which download and delete my uploaded data in `codeigniter`. It's my viewer and it only shows the file name and date from the database which I had uploaded

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><h2>". $row->filename ."</h2></td>";
  echo "<td><h2>". $row->date ."</h2></td>";
  echo "<td><h2>".$row->filelink."</h2></td>";
  //now how can i make download and delete from my database
  //my database contains filename,fileid,filelink       
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

My model is

```
function showfile()
{
  $this->db->select('filename, filelink, date');
  $query = $this->db->get('upload_file');   
  return $query->result();
}
```

My controller

```
function index()
{
  $this->load->model('showuploadmodel');
  $data['query']=$this->showuploadmodel->showfile(); 
  $this->load->view('showupload_view',$data);
}
```

I want to add a delete link and download link and delete only a specific row from database and download a file for which a Id is passed. How can I pass field from database into download helper?

Comment: You're basically asking us to write your application. **Try it**, using help from the user guide, SO, Google, etc., and if you have a specific error or problem, come back and ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass field to controller that calls download helper and not to downloadhelper itself

try this

```
 foreach($query as $row)
 {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h2>". $row->filename ."</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>". $row->date ."</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>".$row->filelink."</h2></td>";
     echo "<td><h2><a href='".site_url('path/to/controllers/download/'.$row->id)."'>Download</a></h2></td>";
     echo "<td><h2><a href='".site_url('path/to/controllers/delete/'.$row->id)."'>Delete</a></h2></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

and in controller add related function

```
 function download($id){
       //$id is that particular Id 
      //do stuff with download helper
 }

 function delete($id){
       //$id is that particular Id 
       //delete code
 }
```